# ruby check a range of dates using date object?

Tags: ruby, class, oop, methods

I am new to ruby. I am practising booking a holiday on a fake airbnb but I want to check if the dates I want (start_of_holiday to end_of_holiday) is available in the dates of the room(start_date - end_date) but I can't seem to compare the ranges or convert the dates into ranges. Is there a better way of checking? thank you

```
require 'date'
    
start_of_holiday = Date.parse("2022-10-02").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
end_of_holiday = Date.parse("2022-10-05").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

start_date = '2022-10-01'
end_date = '2022-10-11'
    
print true if (start_of_holiday..end_of_holiday).include?(start_date..end_date)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're passing a range to `include?` which will return false in this case as the whole range `(start_date..end_date)` is not in `(start_of_holiday..end_of_holiday)`.

From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html#method-i-include-3F);

> include?(obj) → true or false
>
> Returns true if obj is an element of the range, false otherwise.

You could simply adjust it to check for `start_of_holiday` and `end_of_holiday`

```
(start_date..end_date).cover?(start_of_holiday) && (start_date..end_date).cover?(end_of_holiday)
# true
```

Comment: Starting with Ruby 3.0 you can pass a range to [`cover?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Range.html#cover-3F-method)